# Speed up model property of _set in Django

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

I have a relatively simple setup with a string of `Parent`->`Child` relationships.

```
**Parent   Child**
Site     BU
BU       CT
CT       Line
Line     WS
WS       Assess
```

So each child has `models.ForeignKey(Parent)`

The business logic is structured like a pyramid.

Line's level (1-2-3) is dependent on all of it's childs WS level.

A CT's level is dependent on all of it's line's level.

BU's level on CTs level
Site on BUs level.

For example:

```
WS1 \   
WS2 - line 1  --  CT 1 -\ 
WS3 /           /        \
      line 2  -/          \
                  CT 2 --  BU 1 -\
        ..                        Site 1   
        ..        CT 3 --  BU 2 -/
        ..
      line 9  --  CT 4 -/
line 10 -/
```

***Here's the issue:***

Each level has a property to set the color. 
Asking for the Site color (top of the pyramid) initiates **1266 queries** on my development database with a minimum amount of dummy data. That is a huge amount.

Does anyone know how to better model the color property?

It is taking a 4+ seconds to get the site color on a production server with only a few sites, with the intent of adding many additional ones.

`model.py excerpt:`

```
class CT(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    BU = models.ForeignKey(BU, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
    def _color(self):
        workstations = self.line_set.all()
        num_of_workstations = len(workstations)
        high_count = 0

        for workstation in workstations:
            if workstation.color == "high":
                high_count = high_count + 1
        elif workstation.color == "No Assessments completed":
            num_of_workstations = num_of_workstations - 1
    if num_of_workstations <=0:
            return "No Assessments completed"
    else:
        if high_count/num_of_workstations > 0.1:
            return "high"
        elif high_count > 0:
            return "medium"
        else:
            return "low"
    color = property(_color)

class Line(models.Model):
    ct= models.ForeignKey(CT, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    def _color(self):
        wts = self.wt_set.all()
        num_of_wts = len(wts)
        high_count = 0

        for wt in wts:
            if wt.color == "high":
                high_count = high_count + 1
            elif wt.color == "No Assessments completed":
                num_of_wts = num_of_wts - 1
        if num_of_wts <=0:
            return "No Assessments completed"
        else:
            if high_count/num_of_wts > 0.1:
                return "high"
            elif high_count > 0:
                return "medium"
            else:
                return "low"
    color = property(_color)  


class WS(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def _color(self):
        try:
            latest_assessment = self.assessment_set.latest()
            return latest_assessment.color
        except:
            return "No Assessments completed"
    color=property(_color)
```

Comment: *1266 queries* is alot

Comment: Agreed - that's why I'm asking for help!

Comment: I can't really understand your code but you should be looking to use `select_related` and `prefetch_related`, probably in your view.